# Unity Launcher Refuses to Hide

Tags: 12.04, unity, launcher

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and things went surprisingly well so far as I can tell.  The one big issue I have right now is that I can't get the launcher to hide or dodge windows.  I've gone into Appearance / Behavior and set the "hide launcher" to ON, but I'm getting no launcher hiding love.  Is there something I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was installing compizconfig-settings-manager, checking off "enable Unity plugin" and setting the Hide Launcher mode--Unity ran fine before this, just didn't dock.

[image: compizconfig unity plugin]!

Comment: The Unity plugin is enabled and the settings under behavior are as they appear in Appearances / Behavior.  Launcher is set to auto-hide and the target is set for top left corner.  I actually have tried changing the target to the other option, left side, but it has no effectl

Comment: It seems certain applications can make the launcher unfriendly: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1753562. I wound up replacing mine with a dock. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!